# React Function call not working when mapped in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a function which finds a JSON data in React and it's working (I checked using console.log), but when I map in div using JSX ({myFunction.map()}) it doesn't show any output at all. I've tried using console.log in that section it's not working either.

States:

```
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
```

Here is the get request:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(
      "secret-url"
    ).then((res) => {
      setCoins(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);  **//This cosole.log working, showing all json data**
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }, []);
```

Here is function:

```
  const filteredCoins = coins.filter((coin) => {
    coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
    console.log('ABCD'); **// This is working, meaning function is working**
  });
```

JSX Mapping (This Part is not working:

```
<div className="crypto-app">
  {filteredCoins.map(coin => { 
    console.log('ABCD'); **//Not Working**
    return <Coin key={coin.id} name={coin.name} price={coin.current_price} image={coin.image} volume= 
    {coin.volume} symbol={coin.market_cap} /> })}
</div>
```

Comment: I messed up during posting question. But In code console is not working either and neither <Coin/> component is getting rendered.

Comment: Have you proved that the `filteredCoins` list actually has something in it before the map?  Are there errors in the console that might be informative?

Answer (score 2):

`filter` creates a new array containing all the values from the original array for which the function returns `true`.

Your function has no `return` statement so it **always** returns `undefined` so `filteredCoins` is empty.

You then `map` over the empty array so the mapping function never gets called (if it did, it would error because you misspelt `console`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<div className="crypto-app">
   {coins
    .filter((coin) => {`enter code here`
     if (search === "") {
       return coin;
     } else if (
        Object.values(coin)
        .toString()
        .includes(search.toLowerCase())
        ) {
         return coin;
       }
     })
      .map(coin => { 
      console.log('ABCD'); **//Not Working**
      return <Coin key={coin.id} name={coin.name} price={coin.current_price} image= 
      {coin.image} volume= {coin.volume} symbol={coin.market_cap} /> 
     }) 
</div>
```